# Invert a List of Character Vectors in R

Tags: r

What is an efficient way from inverting a list of character vectors as shown below?

## Input

```
lov <- list(v1=c("a", "b"), v2=c("a", "c"), v3=c("a"))
```

## Expected

```
list(a=c("v1", "v2", "v3"), b=c("v1"), c=c("v2"))
```

Similar to [Revert list structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263146/revert-list-structure), but involving vectors:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can either convert the `list` to a `data.frame` (using `stack` or `melt` from `library(reshape2)`) and then `split` the 'ind' column by the 'values' in 'd1'.

```
d1 <- stack(lov)
split(as.character(d1$ind), d1$values)
```

---

Or if the above method is slow, we can replicate (`rep`) the `names` of 'lov' by the `length` of each `list` element (`lengths` gives a `vector` output of the `length` of each element) and `split` it by `unlist`ing the 'lov'.

```
split(rep(names(lov), lengths(lov)), unlist(lov))
```

Comment: The second one is preferrable, since it does not involve added packages

Comment: @cannin The first one also doesn't need any packages.  I was referring to `melt` which comes from `reshape2`.  Otherwise, `stack` is a `base R` function.